# String function for arranging a string in a paritular width in .net

Tags: c#, .net, string

i want to arrange a string in a text file in a fixed length.
Eg:

```
dbrow("ITC_DESC").ToString().Trim().PadRight(20)
```

but the problem is that when a string with more than 20 length it will be widened.
I want to make it fixed.It will need to display only 20 characters.

Comment: So use `Substring` if the length is more than 20. It's pretty easy to write a method to do this, so you only need to write it once...

Comment: I want to know that, is there any library function for that.Because i am using it in a loop.

Comment: Why does the fact that it's in a loop make any difference? You can still a custom method in a loop...

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet. By using below code if the string length is more then 20 than it remove the extra characters from the string.

```
string str = Convert.ToString(dbrow("ITC_DESC")).Trim();
if (str.Length > 20)
{
    str = str.Substring(0,20);
}
else
{
    str = str.PadRight(20);
}
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: There's no point in calling `PadRight` if you've already taken a substring... might as well put that in an `else` block. (I'd also avoid having the constant three times by wrapping this in a method...)